# How many steps to arrive at $(x,y)$ by adding one number to the other?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, functions

I wanted to know if there was a specific formula to solve this problem or can this be solved by any sort of theories like **The Birthday Problem**.

> The problem states that you start off with a pair of numbers $(x_1, y_1) = (1, 1)$. During each round, either $x$ is added to $y$ or $y$ is added to $x$, to get a new $(x_2, y_2)$. We have to figure out the minimum number of rounds to get to $(x_2, y_2)$.

Example:
starting point $(x_1, y_1) = (1, 1)$;
ending point $(x_2, y_2) = (3,5)$.
$$
(1, 1) \mapsto 
(1, 2) \mapsto 
(3, 2) \mapsto 
(3, 5)
$$
Hence, the shortest possible calculations takes $3$ rounds.

Comment: You have chosen an information-free title for your question. Please edit the title so it gives other users some clue as to what the question entails.

Comment: Note that you never get to $(x,y)$ if $\gcd(x,y)>1$. You are essentially generating the Farey sequence, q.v. Start at Stage 0 with the three "fractions", ${0\over1}\ {1\over1}\ {1\over0}$. Then from each pair of adjacent fractions ${a\over b}\ {c\over d}$ create the mediant ${a+c\over b+d}$. So Stage 1 looks like ${0\over1}\ {1\over2}\ {1\over1}\ {2\over1}\ {1\over0}$. Stage 2 has $0/1,1/3,1/2,2/3,1/1,3/2,2/1,3/1,1/0$, and so on. The number of rounds to reach $(x,y)$ is the number of the stage at which $x/y$ first appears. There's a ton of literature on Farey fractions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the way to do this is just to run the process in reverse. E.g., let's work out the way (not just the *shortest* way, but the *only* way) to get to $(63,100)$. We must have come from $(63,37)$; there is no other $(a,b)$ that is one step away from $(63,100)$. $(63,37)$ comes only from $(26,37)$, which comes only from $(26,11)$, from $(15,11)$, from $(4,11)$, from $(4,7)$, from $(4,3)$, from $(1,3)$, from $(1,2)$, from $(1,1)$. So we have $$(1,1)\to(1,2)\to(1,3)\to(4,3)\to(4,7)\to(4,11)\to(15,11)\to(26,11)\to(26,37)\to(63,37)\to(63,100)$$

Comment: What about negatives? $(-37, 100)$ gets to $(63, 100)$ by $x = x+y$, but my guess its the same number of steps anyway.

Comment: @Junk, the problem says you start off with $(1,1)$, and after that you're always adding, so negative numbers can't arise (going forward).

Comment: Both your answers, are really good, but I prefer using **Farey sequence**, the thing is that I need this for a challenge, I am currently figuring out to get it done without using much computation. Larger numbers such as "1000000000 = 10^9".

Comment: Well, it's really just adding up the quotients you get when you do Euclid's algorithm, which is known to be a very fast algorithm, even for very large numbers. $100=1\times63+37$; $63=1\times37+26$; $37=1\times26+11$; $26=2\times11+4$; $11=2\times4+3$; $4=1\times3+1$; $3=3\times1$; $1+1+1+2+2+1+3=11$, so $11$ steps.